# How to find a term

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to generate a formula, as shown, which will search a term in column D.

[image: in this picture]

```
=IF(SUM(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("blue",D1:D))*1),"1","0")
```

but I see the error `#Value!`.

Have you an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be because you are trying to sum strings. Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("blue",D1:D))*1))
```